# FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated event not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I current have a working claims environment in my MVC 5 application which is defining a claims authorization manager statically.

However I want to be able to set my claims authorization manager dynamically so that I can inject some services into using autofac.

I've subscribed to the `FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated` event in my `Application_Start` method but it's never called and therefore there's no claims authentication manager.

If I break point at the event handle setting code all of the other modules are listed (as I still define them statically).

Does anybody have any ideas what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I do the following steps:

**AppStart**

```
...
using System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration;
using System.IdentityModel.Services;

protected void Application_Start()
 ...
 FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfigurationCreated += FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated;      
}

void FederatedAuthentication_FederationConfigurationCreated(object sender, FederationConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
            // Replace the below with your implementation
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   ...
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    ...
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler/>
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
</configuration>
```

I found this article very useful when implementing it.

http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/03/07/claims-based-authentication-in-net4-5-mvc4-with-c-external-authentication-with-ws-federation-part-1/

**Update**

I also have the following in `system.identityModel` config.

```
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthenticationManager type="namespace.webproject.CustomClaimsTransformer,namespace.webproject" />
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="namespace.webproject.CustomAuthorisationManager,namespace.webproject" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried emptying my <system.identityModel.services> section so that it matches this above and moved the configuration into code but still didn't work. I've also now tried IIS instead of IIS Express but that didn't work. Did you also have a <system.identitymodel> section ? What did this look like ?

Comment: Ah interesting, so you need some sort of CustomAuthorisationManager value before you can use the event to change it to the 'real' one using the fired event ?

Comment: I use this as a central point for Authorisation, it makes it more granular. I also use a mix of standard [Authorize] when I only want to restrict via role (which is a claim) but if I want the ClaimsAuth' manager to kick in I use ThinkTecture attributes or manually call it if I am passing more than cached claims to it.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get the FederationConfigurationEventCreated event to fire.  It turns out I was calling a bunch of Federation startup code `(IdentityConfig.ConfigureIdentity())` before I wired up the event -- my bad!